# reading external xml file in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to read xml file in xslt but not able to do that. xslt and xml both the files are present in the same directory. For local testing i am keeping them in D drive.

**external xml (Test.xml):-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report>
    <Doc>
        <DName>Sample</DName>
    </Doc>
</Report>
```

**xslt to read file:-**

```
<ns0:Data>
<xsl:value-of select="document('D://Data//Test.xml')/Report/Doc/DName"/>
  </ns0:Data>
```

Comment: The operator `//` allowed in xpath-expressions to express any descendant node is not allowed inside the path to a file given as argument to the `document(path-to-filename)` function. You have to give the full path to the file you want to read as argument, separating the names of the several sub-directories with a single `/`.

Comment: If they are in the same directory, relative path should be fine and you can just use "Test.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the XML file in a browser, e.g. Chrome. Copy the URL from the address bar.

```
<ns0:Data xmlns:ns0="something">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('file:///D:/Data/Test.xml')/Report/Doc/DName"/>
</ns0:Data>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the external XML file is in the same directory as the XSLT stylesheet file, then you should be able to read from it using a relative path:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('Test.xml')/Report/Doc/DName"/>
```